# Wordpress column-count sort

Tags: html, css, wordpress, posts

I have a div.content with posts and I use column-count to show 2 columns but my posts are display like this http://i.imgur.com/kaX6Zol.png but I want display this http://i.imgur.com/8pIorvC.png . From left to right.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code:

HTML

```
<div id="placeholder">
<div class="post">
    Post 1
</div>
<div class="post">
    Post 2
</div>
<div class="post">
    Post 3
</div>
<div class="post">
    Post 4
</div>
```

CSS

```
#placeholder {
 width:200px;
}

.post{
 width:40%;
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:center;
 border:thin solid #000;
 margin-top:10px;
}
```

See the code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/zfq4q3mn/